# Issue while extracting dictionary of dictionary inside a pandas dataframe and concatenating them?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I have data frame  which I extracted from an api which contains dictionary of dictionary values inside the column called `content`

```
b = json.loads(response.text)
json =pd.json_normalize(b)
df = pd.DataFrame(json)
```

**Sample data of `df`**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0ewrjceiahrlqt/sample.csv?dl=0

I want extract `properties,properties[infotags],properties[location],location['geo']` from`df['content']` and create a new dataframe having these values.

**My code**

```
content =pd.Series(df['content']).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)
content =content.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(content['properties'])
infotags = pd.Series(df2['infotags']).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)
infotags =infotags.reset_index(drop=True)
content_jm = pd.concat([df2, infotags], axis = 1).drop('infotags', axis = 1)

location =pd.Series(content_jm['locations']).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)
geo=pd.json_normalize(location['geo'])
```

How can this be done in python? I am having issue while trying to concatenate them.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example/sample of your json in the question instead of a separate file?

Comment: @YOLO, Its big one with multiple levels, hard to paste it here.